# Is there a way to specify the build directory for py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I can set the final `dist` directory of py2exe using the command line:

```
python setup.py py2exe -d "my/dist/dir"
```

but I can't seem to set the file to use for the interim `build` directory. I've taken a brief look at the source, but unless I am missing something there doesn't appear to be any way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any option that you can set on the command line you can set either through a [setup.cfg](http://docs.python.org/distutils/configfile.html) file or in your setup.py file.

`-d` is a shortcut for `--dist-dir` which you can add to the py2xe dict in the dictionary passed to the options keyword param of setup as `'dist_dir'`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# equivalent command line with options is:
# python setup.py py2exe --compressed --bundle-files=2 --dist-dir="my/dist/dir" --dll-excludes="w9xpopen.exe"
options = {'py2exe': {
           'compressed':1,  
           'bundle_files': 2, 
           'dist_dir': "my/dist/dir"
           'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe']
           }}
setup(console=['myscript.py'], options=options)
```

You could also put [setup.cfg](http://docs.python.org/distutils/configfile.html) next to your setup.py file:

```
[py2exe]
compressed=1
bundle_files=2 
dist_dir=my/dist/dir
dll_excludes=w9xpopen.exe
```

The build directory (`--build-base`) is an option of the build command so you can add it to one of the config files (or the setup.py) as:

```
[build]
build_base=my/build/dir
```

Comment: This doesn't completely work though. I can specify the `dist` dir just as you suggest, but `py2exe` also uses an intermediate `build` directory that I can't seem to change.

Comment: Oops. Missed the build dir part :)

Comment: No problem. I've actually dug into the py2exe source and might make some modifications myself here. When I get a few extra hours.

Comment: I added the info for setting the build directory btw (in case that wasn't obvious).

Answer (score 6):

To clarify on lambacck's answer, this works on the latest vanilla py2exe:

```
options = {'build': {'build_base': 'my/build/dir'},
           'py2exe': {
           'compressed':1,  
           'bundle_files': 2, 
           'dist_dir': "my/dist/dir"
           'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe']
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem as Casey. We have a build system I'd like to conform to
when generating a .exe with py2exe.

However I don't think lambacck's answer works.
'build_base' is not an option of py2exe

To prove it run this:
python setup.py --help py2exe

This should list all the options for py2exe.
'build_base' is not listed in there.

I'm using py2exe 0.6.9

I could be wrong, but it sounds like someone needs to send a patch to whoever
maintains this project. It's on SourceForge and hasn't been touch since 2008.