# Use applications built by Py2Exe in a directory other than the original one?

Tags: python, py2exe

I am using Py2Exe to build an application.

It works well when I double click the application in the original project folder, all the graphical interfaces appear on the screen.

However, when I copy and paste the project to another directory, the application just gives a cmd window. The graphical interfaces don't appear on the screen.

May I know how can I work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: are you copying all the contents of the dist folder to the other directory?

Comment: @user2963623 Yes, I copied the whole project folder to another directory. Everything is included.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811960/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-build-directory-for-py2exe.

Comment: Might be unrelated to this, but just make sure that if you are using any icons/pictures, include them in the dist folder. You might try building a standalone exe

Comment: @user2963623 I've checked all the copied and used stuff. All I used externally is just `msvcp90.dll` and a `.png` image, and I am sure that  they are copied to both the project directory (where the source code locates) and the application directory (where the compiled application locates).

Comment: I've never faced such a problem before. Another option you can try is using pyinstaller to make the exe. Their recent versions have made the job really easy.